# if condition syntax error

Tags: bash, if-statement

I wrote a simple script to check if a number is between 20 and 30:

```
while true 
do
echo 'enter a number between 20 and 30'
 read e
 if  [ $e  -lt 30] && [$e -gt 20 ]
 then
    echo ' you entered desired number' && break
fi
done
```

but it has a error as follows:

> line 5: [: missing `]'

where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space here:

```
if [ $e -lt 30 ] && [ $e -gt 20 ]
              ^      ^
              |      |
              |      |
---------------------
```

Always try and run the bash script in debug mode. To run your script in debug mode, simply do the following on your command prompt.

`bash -x scriptname.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You need some whitespace around the `[` and `]`:

```
if [ $e -lt 30 ] && [ $e -gt 20 ]
```

Since `[` can be a program*, you have to treat it like you're passing in command line arguments.

* I say can be as it might be internalized by some shells

Answer (score 2):

you need a space between the number and the bracket. Line 5 should read

```
if  [ $e  -lt 30 ] && [ $e -gt 20 ]
```